# webp content type error

Tags: android, browser, webp

I have converted images from jpg to webp in order to save bandwidth on android 4.2 or newer. I've saved about 80% bandwidth without any noticeable loss. However I found out that this didn't yield satisfying results. Actually, some browsers even yielded negative results.
Later I found out that the Content-Type entity-header field indicates that the image is jpg (sometimes doc) but actually it is webp. Does this field matter? I find it works well on most browsers but I am afraid there are some exceptions.

Here is an example: [My Webp image link](http://t11.baidu.com/it/u=2691924769,3069828568&fm=79)

Thanks in advance.